# Passing values from One SQL Query to another and use the IF Statement to determine the result

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to do something I have never done before.  I have the following SQL Queries:

```
SELECT a.UserID, u.Initials, u.Surname, u.Email, u.CountryID
FROM [dbo].[App] a
INNER JOIN [dbo].[User] u  ON a.UserID = u.ID
WHERE a.ID = 46451
```

This query return the following information:

> UserID: 51637
>
> Initials:    T
>
> Surname: Tester
>
> Email: petercash@live.co.za
>
> CountryID: 203

Now I would like to take the CountryID returned which is 203 and check if it exists in the sadc table and if it does, then use it to retrieve data from the cost table

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) AS counted FROM [dbo].[Sadc] WHERE CountryID = 203) > 0) 
  SELECT Cost FROM [dbo].[Cost] WHERE ID = 4
```

The `a.ID` (In the WHERE clause) in the first SQL Query to be a parameter(as the value will change every time).
Then take the value of the `CountryID` and pass it to the second query and return the `cost` from the Cost table

Comment: What is the 4 in `WHERE ID = 4` in the 2nd query?

Comment: the 4 is the costid from the cost Table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pretty much typed in the best way to do this in your question.

```
SELECT Cost 
FROM [dbo].[Cost] 
WHERE ID = 4
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Sadc] WHERE CountryID = 203)
```

Comment: yeah that's better than my solution

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a variable to hold the value and use an `EXISTS` statement to check if it is in the table:

```
-- variable to hold the value
DECLARE @CountryId INT

-- this set's the value of @CountryId
SELECT @CountryId = u.CountryID
FROM [dbo].[App] a
INNER JOIN [dbo].[User] u  ON a.UserID = u.ID
WHERE a.ID = 46451

-- check if it exists in [Sadc]
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Sadc] WHERE CountryID = @CountryId)
BEGIN
    -- run your code if it exists
    SELECT Cost FROM [dbo].[Cost] WHERE ID = 4
END
```

Comment: this would go into a stored  procedure if I am correct ? I just wanna try out both answers

Comment: yeah, I assumed you wanted it in a stored proc.